# How can I make code wait for the return of an API call - Node.js

Tags: node.js, api, async-await, request

I am trying to write a function which makes an API call and wait until the API has returned a value, how do I improve my code to do this. At the moment it just returns Promise-pending.

```
async function getData(options){

    
    const result = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request(options, function(error, response) {
        if (error) return reject(error);
            
        return resolve(JSON.parse(response.body));
        });
    });
    
    var fromapi = await result;
    
    return fromapi;

};
```

Comment: Try just doing ` await new Promise` without storing it in a var

Comment: `request` is [deprecated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request), you should consider using [`http.request()`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_url_options_callback), it won't be difficult to accomplish this method you're trying to implement. Or possibly consider [`axios`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios).

Comment: @bluejayke But if I need to use the result from this API request, how to I assigned it to a variable?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
const request = require('request')

function makeRequest(uri, options) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        return request(uri, options, function (error, response) {
            if (error) reject(error);
            resolve(response.body);
        });
    });
}

async function getData(options) {
    const result = await makeRequest('https://google.com', options)
    console.log(result)
}

getData().then(() => {

}).catch((e) => {
   console.log(e)
})
```